# Graphics drivers for Intel Nuc (DE3815TYKE)

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics

I'm searching for the graphics drivers for my Nuc with Ubuntu 14.04.

I found and installed *"Intel Graphics Installer for Linux"* which run fine but without effect. I updated the kernel (3.13 to 3.14.1)

I have to play 1080p videos, but it's still not fluid...

The hardware is new. It's maybe the cause the drivers are missing, but on PC with NVidia cards, I had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Oibaf's graphics driver PPA?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

You may also want to check whether or not you are actually getting a functional driver with `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`.

Comment: Thx for your reply.

It may seems to be a little better, but I'm not sure...


It's still the CPU which is used to decode the video :(

Comment: glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Bay Trail
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.0-devel (git-0d5ec2c trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.0-devel (git-0d5ec2c trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)

the line break don't work ? Ô_o

Comment: Line breaks don't work on comments. It seems your GPU is fine, but if you are trying to get it to decode video with the GPU, you do need to make sure that you have the hardware decoding packages installed. That would be `mesa-vdpau-drivers` in trusty. You may also want to check whether your video player is using vdpau, X11, or OpenGL for playback.

Comment: I managed to make it work... But honestly, i don't know which package worked... May be ubuntu-restricted-extras or mesa-vdpau-drivers... Anayway, it work better with VP8/WEBM than H264/MP4,... But it work ! Thank you for your help !