# Ubuntu 14.04 and Intel NUC5i5RYH - Choppy Video Playback

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-nuc

I have just installed 14.04 and tried playing videos via YouTube and am getting very choppy video playback - it almost looks like i am watching the video via a remote desktop session.

I tried a suggestion from the following link with no luck: [Graphics drivers for Intel Nuc (DE3815TYKE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475782/graphics-drivers-for-intel-nuc-de3815tyke)

The hardware is a 5th generation i5 intel nuc with 8GB ram and a 120GB ssd.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Cheers,
Arnie